# Probability Question based on two die. Divide the product by a multiple of three

Tags: probability

A die is rolled four times. What is the probability that exactly two multiples of 3 are rolled?

I know that the multiples of 3 in the dice are only 3 and 6.
Therefore there would be a for getting three or six would be :

$\frac{2}{6}$$=$$\frac{1}{3}$

Then since there are two die we would have to multiple them together so we get:
$\frac{1}{3}$$*$$\frac{1}{3}$$=$$\frac{1}{9}$

This is the part that I don't understand. Would I have to multiply four like this : $4$$*$$\frac{1}{9}$ to get $\frac{4}{9}$ or would I have to do something else.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to get a three on *both* of them.  Just on one of them.  Can you gigure out what to do. (I have to admit I have no idea what you think multiplying by 4 would achieve.)

Comment: So are you looking for the probability of getting $2$ multiples of threes or having the product be a multiple of $3$? "What is the probability that exactly two multiples of 3 are rolled?" implies the former.

Answer (score 1):

Let probability of event A be P(A)
& probability of event B be P(B)

Provided that event A is independent of event B,
The probability of BOTH A & B Happening = P(A AND B) = P(A) * P(B)

We write it as P(A $\cap$ B) = P(A) $\times$ P(B)

Hope this helps

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)

Comment: What the problem?